# How can I print lines of a .csv file to a python dictionary without using any modules, while including the headers as keys with each value?

Tags: python, dictionary, data-serialization

For example, say my data is in the form:

```
Column A,Column B
Cell 1,Cell 2
Cell 3,Cell 4
```

and I want to end up with several dictionaries that look like:

```
{"Column A":"Cell 1", "Column B":"Cell 2"}
{"Column A":"Cell 3", "Column B":"Cell 4"}
{"Column A":"Cell 5", "Column B":"Cell 6"}
```

The csv file I'm using has several named columns, and I want to basically print a dictionary using the column header as the key, with it's associated cell as the value. Right now I seem to be stuck either printing a dictionary like:

```
{"Column A":"Cell 1", "Cell 2"}
```

or just being able to get a dictionary for one value like:

```
{"Column A":"Cell 1"}
```

I've looked up similar problems on here already, but I'm still new to python and can't seem to figure out the answer for this specific problem.

```
with open('file_name.csv') as filename:
    linelist = []
    output_dict = {}
    for i in filename:
        linelist.append(i.split(","))
        for line in linelist:
            header = linelist[0]
            value = linelist[1:]
            for j in line:
                output_dict.update({header[0]:line[0]})
```

At this point this is what I have, but I've just been aimlessly trying to add and take away parts of it so this doesn't even work now.

Comment: You should first work through the [Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/) or another suitable tutorial if not done yet.

Comment: Your proposed output is not a dictionary. It is several dictionaries

Comment: There are no commas in your "my data is in the form" content.  Perhaps post  your *actual* input file.  Have you considered how to handle commas in the cell data itself?  Is quoting of the cell fields expected or allowed?  There are reasons there are built-in modules for this as it gets complicated.

Comment: @MichaelButscher I've worked through several tutorials but have a difficult time relating them to problems that I come across on my own. Thank you though, more studying is definitely needed.

Comment: @MarkTolonen I've adjusted the format of the input file to match what the csv actually looks like, my apologies. I am trying to do a code challenge on my own, but the requirement is that I do not import any modules.

Comment: @CtrlZ Thank you again, I have adjusted my requirements to make it clear.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it following way, let `file.csv` content be

```
columnA,columnB
cell1,cell2
cell3,cell4
```

then

```
with open("file.csv", "r") as f:
    headers = next(f).strip().split(",")
    for line in f:
        print(dict(zip(headers,line.strip().split(","))))
```

gives output

```
{'columnA': 'cell1', 'columnB': 'cell2'}
{'columnA': 'cell3', 'columnB': 'cell4'}
```

Explanation: firstly I create list of headers, to do so I instruct python to consume 1st line (`next(f)`), remove leading and trailing whitespace characters (`.split()`) and split at commas. For each following line I do same thing to given line and then use dict-zip to create dictionary from two lists, where elements at same position in each list are key value pair.

Comment: But that isn't what the source data look like.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. I made a mistake formatting the original source data but this is what the source data looks like, and the output is exactly what I needed. I was overthinking things as usual, not considering zip() as an option. Thank you very much.